# Trying to import list from Sharepoint to Excel

Tags: sharepoint, vba, sharepoint-2010, excel

I am trying to import a Sharepoint list into an Excel 2010 worksheet.
The code below worked in 2003 but does not work in Excel 2010.

```
Set TempSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add
TempSheet.Name = ("TEMP")
Set TempSheet2 = Sheets("TEMP")
TempSheet2.Activate    

------ the code below is the issue ----------------

Dim src(2) As Variant
src(0) = "https://REDACTED/exceptions/_vti_bin/"
src(1) = "{72B6638E-0E7B-4B37-A6A5-3142033E4E02}"
src(2) = "{163702D0-A380-467F-B883-1195F4F40616}"

TempSheet2.ListObjects.Add xlSrcExternal, src, True, xlYes, TempSheet2.Range("A2")
```

I get the run time error message 1004. Initialization of the data source failed.

Comment: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/29021/import-sharepoint-list-into-excel-using-vba-only

Comment: I tried this code and I get the same error message as the above user.  It's basically the same code that I am using in my macro.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't run into this myself, but OfficeWriter has a sharepoint plugin that exports data from lists into excel workbooks. See http://www.officewriter.com/sharepoint. Disclaimer: I didn't work on this plugin, but I did work on the last version of OfficeWriter.